# EF Code First not loading properties of one Entity in a hierarchy, but loading anothers

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following (very weird) problem.

I have a database defined that has a bunch of entities using EF5 Code First (latest bits). One of those entities is an abstract class for the Users of the system.

This abstract class has two concrete classes beneath it, one for local users (users authenticated against the DB) and another one for domain users (users whose authentication is taken care of by a DC).

The weird behavior is that when I load a row from the DB (using EF) if the instance is a LocalUser everything works perfectly and all navigation properties are populated. But when I load a DomainUser, only the base properties are loaded and all navigation properties are null.

Another important thing is that all navigation properties are defined in the Abstract User class, the concrete classes only handle the authentication for each type of user.

Comment: Can you provide some code on how are you loading these instances? Are you using the OfType() method to load them?

Comment: Can you post your DbContext, i want to see how your context is being set up with the inherited entities.